# Automatically Zip SQL Backup Files

Tags: compression, windows-server-2012

I have a windows server 2012 server pulling a backup of my database every day but need to compress it.  Can I use Task Scheduler to automatically zip my SQL file and delete the larger original file?

Comment: Why not write a batch file to do this?  Of course you should be able to create the dump and compress it using any number of tools

Comment: Short answer. Yes

Comment: Can you recommend me a tool/link? I've tried using 7Zip but have been unsuccessful with their tutorials. Also, size of my zip files from 7zip seem to be nearly double than that of a zip file from winzip.